# How to download or copy files sent to me in Dropbox to my PC or USB thumb drive

Tags: dropbox, download

Someone put files in Dropbox for me and I want to download them, or copy them to my PC (or a USB thumb drive). But I don't see where I indicate I want the file downloaded/copied!

Answer (score 2):

I would expect there to be a download button (top right):

[image: WA73853 example]

It is quite prominent so presumably you are *not* seeing it, hence some further details might be relevant. Might you post a link to an image of what you do see?